# Dual boot Windows10-Debian

Tags: debian, boot, dual-boot

I recently installed Windows 10 and Debian 10 as a dual boot system. After one day Windows did not boot anymore (The Windows symbol appears and then it gives an error message).

I used bootinfoscript to produce the following, but I do not know how to interpret it. Can anyone help?

Here is the script:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at this location and looks 
    in partition 108 for .

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /bootmgr /Boot/BCD

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       Extended Partition
    Boot sector type:  Unknown
    Boot sector info: 

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Debian GNU/Linux 10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sda6: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda7: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda8: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda9: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 698,7 GiB, 750156374016 bytes, 1465149168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MK7559GS
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1               2,048    29,384,703    29,382,656  27 Hidden NTFS (Recovery Environment)
/dev/sda2    *     29,386,752    29,591,551       204,800   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda3          29,591,552   420,216,551   390,625,000   7 NTFS / exFAT / HPFS
/dev/sda4         420,216,830 1,465,147,391 1,044,930,562   5 Extended
/dev/sda5         420,216,832   469,045,247    48,828,416  83 Linux
/dev/sda6         469,047,296   488,577,023    19,529,728  83 Linux
/dev/sda7         488,579,072   490,577,919     1,998,848  82 Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda8         490,579,968   494,483,455     3,903,488  83 Linux
/dev/sda9         494,485,504 1,465,147,391   970,661,888  83 Linux


"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        9AE238B5E2389789                       ntfs       
/dev/sda2        ACEA3EB8EA3E7F20                       ntfs       
/dev/sda3        6AD6457DD6454B11                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829   ext4       
/dev/sda6        5c2adc6b-d436-4079-a425-8b926d23493f   ext4       
/dev/sda7        5ba41787-3509-48cd-8828-b42c36f7e5b0   swap       
/dev/sda8        1357acd1-7437-4b95-b453-42099dbdd856   ext4       
/dev/sda9        ee9f58db-913b-45fe-b0f1-16edcff73076   ext4       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda5        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda6        /var                     ext4       (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda8        /tmp                     ext4       (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda9        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos5' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=de_DE
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=5
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=5
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,msdos5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos5' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
fi
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/futureprototype-theme/grub/grub-4x3.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
else
  set menu_color_normal=cyan/blue
  set menu_color_highlight=white/blue
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
}
set linux_gfx_mode=
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829' {
    load_video
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,msdos5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos5' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
    fi
    echo    'Linux 4.19.0-13-686-pae wird geladen …'
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-686-pae root=UUID=80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829 ro  quiet
    echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-13-686-pae
}
submenu 'Erweiterte Optionen für Debian GNU/Linux' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829' {
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, mit Linux 4.19.0-13-686-pae' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-13-686-pae-advanced-80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos5' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.19.0-13-686-pae wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-686-pae root=UUID=80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829 ro  quiet
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-13-686-pae
    }
    menuentry 'Debian GNU/Linux, with Linux 4.19.0-13-686-pae (recovery mode)' --class debian --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.19.0-13-686-pae-recovery-80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829' {
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_msdos
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,msdos5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos5' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos5 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos5  80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.19.0-13-686-pae wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.19.0-13-686-pae root=UUID=80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829 ro single 
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.19.0-13-686-pae
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows 10 (auf /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-chain-ACEA3EB8EA3E7F20' {
    insmod part_msdos
    insmod ntfs
    set root='hd0,msdos2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-ieee1275='ieee1275//disk@0,msdos2' --hint-bios=hd0,msdos2 --hint-efi=hd0,msdos2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,msdos2  ACEA3EB8EA3E7F20
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root ACEA3EB8EA3E7F20
    fi
    parttool ${root} hidden-
    drivemap -s (hd0) ${root}
    chainloader +1
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=80bbdaa0-d136-45f2-875c-5c71e1b65829 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /home was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=ee9f58db-913b-45fe-b0f1-16edcff73076 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# /tmp was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=1357acd1-7437-4b95-b453-42099dbdd856 /tmp            ext4    defaults        0       2
# /var was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=5c2adc6b-d436-4079-a425-8b926d23493f /var            ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
UUID=5ba41787-3509-48cd-8828-b42c36f7e5b0 none            swap    sw              0       0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


======================== Unknown MBRs/Boot Sectors/etc: ========================

Unknown BootLoader on sda4

00000000  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  |................|
*
000001b0  ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff  ff ff ff ff ff ff 00 fe  |................|
000001c0  ff ff 83 fe ff ff 02 00  00 00 00 10 e9 02 00 fe  |................|
000001d0  ff ff 05 fe ff ff 02 10  e9 02 00 08 2a 01 00 00  |............*...|
000001e0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  |................|
000001f0  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00 00 55 aa  |..............U.|
00000200


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-2SK4euCp/Tmp_Log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

Comment: Thanks for reminding me to look up the precise message. It is: "Stop code: Critical process died". It does not seem to be too informative though.

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. So you probably need Windows repairs.

Comment: The problem turned up shortly after I installed Debian (Windows had been running without any problems before), so I made the assumption that there is some kind of connection between the two events.